# How to make substitute command respect different cases

Tags: substitute

Can vim substitute automatically depending on the case ?

like : `s/foo/bar/` turns `Foo` to `Bar` and `foo` to `bar` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easier solution to that is to use the [abolish plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) by Tim Pope. Once it is installed you can use the `:S` command. For example if you have this file:

```
foo
Foo
FOO
```

And run `:%S/foo/bar/` you'll get:

```
bar
Bar
BAR
```

It also provides a lot of command to play with different cases.

---

**Edit** As @LucHermitte said, if you already have the `:S` command used for something else, you might want to use the complete name of abolish's function: `:Subvert`

Comment: In case the user has a plugin that defines command(s) starting with a capital `S`, it may be better to provide the full command name.